# MS-Access Checkbox = Now() On Click ; Uncheck = Null?

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, null

I'm designing a task order db that has a lot of checkboxes and instead of creating Yes/No fields it was decided to use Date fields that use Checkboxes on the Forms to set said dates using the `= Now()` function:

```
Private Sub DXF_Chk_Click()
dxfLimits = Now()
End Sub
```

However, if someone unchecks the checkbox the date just updates and in our Reports the boxes remain checked.

My thought was to write a code that checks to see if the Date field has been filled and Null it `On Click` but that's not working:

```
If Me.DXF_Chk = 1 Then
  Me.dxfLimits = Now()
 Else
  Me.dxfLimits = Null
 End If
```

Or leave the current On Click alone and use some code in the `After_Update event`. I'm not sure which is proper protocol, nor what I'm doing wrong in the code itself.

Sorry, I'm a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
Me.dxfLimits = IIF(Me.DXF_chk, Now(), NULL)
```

Comment: While this works I have a related questions: if you close and open the form the checkbox is blank, regardless of whether or not there is data in the appropriate fields. Should I use an On Load query to make the checkboxes visually show up if data is in the field?

Comment: You don't need a query. Just add to the `OnCurrent` event `Me.DXF_chk=IIF(IsNull(Me.dxfLimits),0,-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub DXF_chk_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.DXF_chk.Value Then
     Me.dxfLimits = Now()
    Else
     Me.dxfLimits = Null
    End If
End Sub
```

OR

```
Private Sub DXF_chk_AfterUpdate()
   If Me.DXF_chk = -1 Then
  Me.dxfLimits = Now()
 Else
  Me.dxfLimits = Null
 End If
End Sub
```

Note: `-1 = true/yes, 0=false/no`

Comment: Hmmm this didn't seem to work for me, unsure why. It would add the date checked, but not null out if unchecked.

Comment: @Calebmcc strange bcoz the answer provided by Sunknight0 also has similar code with some variation. Logically doing the same thing.

Comment: Yeah I don't understand why yours didn't work... but my understanding is pretty low at this point.

Comment: It may work if you use `If Me.DXF_chk = true` instead of `If Me.DXF_chk = -1`

Comment: @SunKnight0 I know the code works but user is unable to use it correctly.

Comment: It is possible the reason is the use of the `AfterUpdate` event instead of the `Click` event. I think `AfterUpdate` only fires after the focus has moved away from the checkbox while the user expects to see an immediate change.

Comment: Yes, it may be.